# Using the Outer Function

Tags: r, outer-join

I'm having difficulty using the outer function. I've looked at a few threads, but haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a matrix, prices, with the following information:
`25 26`
I use the outer function as follows to multiply these numbers together:

```
a = outer(prices[1,1:2],prices[1,1:2],FUN ="*")
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in as.vector(X) %*% t(as.vector(Y)) : 
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

If, however, I do the exact same thing, but with the numbers directly, it works as I would like it to:

```
a = outer(c(25,26),c(25,26),FUN ="*")
```

and returns a 2x2 matrix with the products.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify, I checked (using `class(prices[1,1])`) that the  variables within the prices array were integers.  
Although when I just checked now `class(prices[1,1:2])` it returned "Dataframe" as the type. I'm not sure if there is something I can/need to do about that? Thanks!

Comment: `prices <- as.matrix(prices)`, `outer` only takes matrix/array/vector as arguments not dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prices matrix is apparently a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`. You can either change that:

```
prices <- as.matrix(prices)
a <- outer(prices[1,1:2],prices[1,1:2],FUN ="*")
```

or you can just convert to numeric when you use it:

```
a <- outer(as.numeric(prices[1,1:2]),as.numeric(prices[1,1:2]),FUN ="*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prices <- matrix(c(25,26), nrow=1)
a = outer(prices[1,1:2],prices[1,1:2],FUN ="*")

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  625  650
#[2,]  650  676
```